# Creating Twisted TCP socket and sending test value

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

I am setting up a socket with TCP/IP-protocol, and since my receiver is handling `int8u_t` i would like to know if this approach is correct.

At connection the server has to send a value `mode=int(42)` to the receiver which is done in `def connectionMade(self)`. But i understand there will be some conflicts since the normal int in python is 32-bit and my receiver is only 8-bit, can i somehow cast it or create it in int8u?

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor

class TestSocket(Protocol):
        def connectionMade(self):
                mode=int(42)
                self.factory.clients.append(self)
                self.transport.write(mode)
                print "clients are ", self.factory.clients

        def connectionLost(self, reason):
            self.factory.clients.remove(self)

        def dataReceived(self, data):
                #print "data is ", data
                #a = data.split(':')
                print data
                print "-------------------"

        def message(self, message):
                self.transport.write(message + '\n')

factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = TestSocket()
factory.clients = []

reactor.listenTCP(30002, factory)
print "TestSocket server started"
reactor.run()
```

Comment: `mode=int(42)` can be better expressed as `mode = 42`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use struct

```
from struct import *
mode = pack("h", 42) # 'h' == short
```

edit: Apparently you wanted `pack("I", 42)`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `numpy`:

```
import numpy
mode = numpy.int8(42)  # int8   Byte (-128 to 127)
```

You can find more information for types and conversions between types
using `numpy` [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html).